# loop json object in java using gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Below is a list of device details stored in json format in a json file.

```
{"Device_details":[
    {"DUT1":
        {"Interface":"eth1",
        "IP_address":"40.0.0.1/24"},
     "DUT3":
        {"Interface":"eth3",
        "IP_address":"40.0.0.3/24"},
     "DUT2":
        {"Interface":"eth2",
        "IP_address":"40.0.0.2/24"
        }
    }
             ]}
```

I want to loop through each device and print out the interface and ip address of each device in the list corresponding to the individual DUT.

sample output:

```
Device : DUT1
Interface : eth1
IP_address : 40.0.0.1/24

Device : DUT2
Interface : eth2
IP_address : 40.0.0.2/24
```

and so on....
The order of the devices displayed does not matter and I want to do this using GSON.
My code so far:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(new FileReader(fileName.json));
jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray devices = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("Device_details");
JsonElement device_list = devices.get(0);
JsonObject devices_object= device_list.getAsJsonObject();
System.out.println(devices_object.size());
for (int i=0; i < devices_object.size(); i++){
//How do I access the devices and it's details
        };
```

Comment: does your JSON always have the same structure?

Comment: Have you check how to access the data with GSON ? Tutorial are a good start ;)

Comment: @Rhayene Yes. JSON will always have the same structure. Just the devices keep adding.

Comment: @AxelH I did check and didn't find way to loop thorugh JSON objects as in my case

Comment: you may find  [this](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/) example helpful then. Look at the "Nested JSON Objects" section. If the structure is always the same, you can create a class that matches your JSON. This should make your code much simpler, since you are working with a normal java object after parsing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("pathToJson.json"));
    Response res = gson.fromJson(reader, Response.class);
    for (Map<String, Device> map : res.Device_details) {
        for (Map.Entry<String,Device> e : map.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("Device : " + e.getKey());
            Device device = e.getValue();
            System.out.println("Interface : " + device.Interface);
            System.out.println("IP_address : " + device.IP_address);
        }
    }
}

class Device {
    String Interface;
    String IP_address;
}


class Response {
    List<HashMap<String, Device>> Device_details = new ArrayList();
}
```

`JsonReader` and `gson.fromJson` allow you to map your json into a java Object.

Here, `Response` is the "root element". Its property `Device_details` has to have the same name as in your json.

Comment: This code is good and very new for me, but the output is quite different.


Key : DUT3
Interface : eth3
IP_address : 40.0.0.3/24
Interface : eth1
IP_address : 40.0.0.1/24
Interface : eth2
IP_address : 40.0.0.2/24
Key : DUT1
Interface : eth3
IP_address : 40.0.0.3/24
Interface : eth1
IP_address : 40.0.0.1/24
Interface : eth2
IP_address : 40.0.0.2/24

It prints out the interface details of all the devices for given key. But, it should print details of only the corresponding device.

Comment: In your question : `I want to loop through each device and print out the interface and ip address.`. So, I don't understand what you want. Please, can you update your question to add the expected output? What do you mean by the corresponding device?

Comment: Remember that this doesn't need to be the exact answer. The idea is there, OP can learn from this to adapt to his needs. PS : If you can, you should add a bit of explanation about the class defined at least.